# Azure B2C: Email not displayed during Email MFA

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, aad-b2c

I am using B2C custom policies which allows signup/signin with the username instead of the  email. I have Email MFA enforced during the sign Up.

When signing in and selecting Email MFA, I don't see the email populated.

I have implemented the policies provided in this article https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-email-or-phone

```
        <!--MFA related Attributes-->
        <ClaimType Id="extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail">
                <DisplayName>Please select your preferred MFA method</DisplayName>
                <DataType>string</DataType>
                <UserInputType>RadioSingleSelect</UserInputType>
                <Restriction>
                <Enumeration Text="Phone" Value="phone" SelectByDefault="true" />
                <Enumeration Text="Email " Value="email" SelectByDefault="false" />
                </Restriction>
      </ClaimType>
    <ClaimType Id="readOnlyEmail">
                <DisplayName>Email Address</DisplayName>
                <DataType>string</DataType>
                <UserHelpText/>
                <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>
                    <ClaimType Id="newPhoneNumberEntered">
                        <DisplayName>New Phone Number Entered</DisplayName>
                        <DataType>boolean</DataType>
                    </ClaimType>      

                        <ClaimType Id="userIdForMFA">
                        <DisplayName>UserId for MFA</DisplayName>
                        <DataType>string</DataType>
                    </ClaimType> 
         
         <ClaimType Id="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber">
                        <DisplayName>Phone Number</DisplayName>
                        <DataType>string</DataType>
                        <Mask Type="Simple">XXX-XXX-</Mask>
                        <UserHelpText>Your telephone number</UserHelpText>
                    </ClaimType>

        <ClaimType Id="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber">
                        <DisplayName>Verified Phone Number</DisplayName>
                        <DataType>string</DataType>
                        <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
                        <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="phone_number" />
                        </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
                        <Mask Type="Simple">XXX-XXX-</Mask>
                        <UserHelpText>Your office phone number that has been verified</UserHelpText>
                    </ClaimType>
        </ClaimsSchema>

        <ClaimsTransformations>
        <!--MFA related Transformation Start-->
              <ClaimsTransformation Id="CopySignInNameToReadOnly" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
            <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" /> <!--signInName-->
            </InputClaims>
            <InputParameters>
            <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0}" />
            </InputParameters>
            <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
            </OutputClaims>
        </ClaimsTransformation>
        <ClaimsTransformation Id="CopyEmailToReadOnly" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
            <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" /> 
            </InputClaims>
            <InputParameters>
            <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0}" />
            </InputParameters>
            <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
            </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>  
            <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateUserIdForMFA" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0}@{RelyingPartyTenantId}" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userIdForMFA" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation> 


        <!--MFA related transformation end-->



            <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateSubjectClaimFromObjectID" TransformationMethod="CreateStringClaim">
                <InputParameters>
                    <InputParameter Id="value" DataType="string" Value="Not supported currently. Use oid claim." />
                </InputParameters>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sub" TransformationClaimType="createdClaim" />
                </OutputClaims>
            </ClaimsTransformation>
            <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateEmailsFromOtherMailsAndSignInNamesInfo" TransformationMethod="AddItemToStringCollection">
                <InputClaims>
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNamesInfo.emailAddress" TransformationClaimType="item" />
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
                </InputClaims>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emails" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
                </OutputClaims>
            </ClaimsTransformation>
            <ClaimsTransformation Id="AddStrongAuthenticationEmailToEmails" TransformationMethod="AddItemToStringCollection">
                <InputClaims>
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" TransformationClaimType="item" />
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emails" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
                </InputClaims>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emails" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
                </OutputClaims>
            </ClaimsTransformation>
            <ClaimsTransformation Id="AssertEmailAndstrongAuthenticationEmailAddressAreEqual" TransformationMethod="AssertStringClaimsAreEqual">
                <InputClaims>
                    <!--<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mail" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1" />  -->
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1" /> 
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim2" />
                </InputClaims>
                <InputParameters>
                    <InputParameter Id="stringComparison" DataType="string" Value="ordinalIgnoreCase" />
                </InputParameters>
            </ClaimsTransformation>
            <ClaimsTransformation Id="AssertAccountEnabledIsTrue" TransformationMethod="AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue">
                <InputClaims>
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountEnabled" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
                </InputClaims>
                <InputParameters>
                    <InputParameter Id="valueToCompareTo" DataType="boolean" Value="true" />
                </InputParameters>
            </ClaimsTransformation>
            
</ClaimsTransformations>


        
            
                <!--defination for MFA phone factor-->
                     <ContentDefinition Id="api.phonefactor">
                        <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/multifactor-1.0.0.cshtml</LoadUri>
                        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
                        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:multifactor:1.2.5</DataUri>
                        <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="DisplayName">Multi-factor authentication page</Item>
                        </Metadata>
                  </ContentDefinition>
                    </ContentDefinitions>
                </BuildingBlocks>



    <ClaimsProviders>
    <!--mFA related-->
        <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CopyEmailToReadOnly" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
        </TechnicalProfile>

        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CopySignInNameToReadOnly" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
        </TechnicalProfile>       
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>




    <!--end of mFa related-->


        <ClaimsProvider>
            <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
            <TechnicalProfiles>
                <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonName">
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
                        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">true</Item>
                    </Metadata>
                    <!--Include the Claims Transformation to populate displayName using the first name and Last name combination-->
                    <InputClaimsTransformations>
                            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateDisplayNameFromFirstNameAndLastName" />
                              <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateOtherMailsFromEmail" /> 
                    </InputClaimsTransformations>
                    <InputClaims>
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.userName" Required="true" />
                    </InputClaims>
                    <PersistedClaims>
                        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.userName" />
                        <!--<PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mail" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" /> -->
                        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
                        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" PartnerClaimType="password" />
                        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType= "displayName" /> <!--DefaultValue="SomeDefaultDisplayNameValue" DefaultValue="unknownUser"-->
                        <!-- Optional claims. -->
                        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
                        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
                        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" /> <!--added on 02162022-->
                    </PersistedClaims>
                    <OutputClaims>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" PartnerClaimType="newClaimsPrincipalCreated" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" /> <!--displayName attribute added- partner claim type Name added-->
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" /> <!--added on02162022-->
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" /> <!--added on 02172022-->
                    </OutputClaims>
                    <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
                    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
                </TechnicalProfile>

            
                <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonName">
                    <DisplayName>User ID signup</DisplayName>
                    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
                        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
                        <Item Key="LocalAccountType">Username</Item>
                        <Item Key="LocalAccountProfile">true</Item>
                        <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
                    </Metadata>
                    <CryptographicKeys>
                        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
                    </CryptographicKeys>
                    <InputClaims>
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
                    </InputClaims>
                    <OutputClaims>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
                            <!-- <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mail" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" /> -->
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" Required="true" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" Required="true" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" Required="true" /> <!--Display Name added-->
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" /> 
                        
                        </OutputClaims>
                    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonName" />
                    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
                </TechnicalProfile>
                <!--AAD User read using Username-->

                <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingUsername-NoError">
                        <Metadata>
                            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
                            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
                            <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">An account could not be found for the provided user ID.</Item>
                        </Metadata>
                        <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
                        <InputClaims>
                            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.userName" Required="true" />
                        </InputClaims>
                        <OutputClaims>
                            <!-- Required claims -->
                            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
                            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
                            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
                            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
                            <!--
                            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
                            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="secondaryStrongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationAlternativePhoneNumber" />
                            -->
                            <!-- Optional claims -->
                            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid" />
                            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" PartnerClaimType="upn" />
                            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
                            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
                            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
                            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
                        </OutputClaims>
                        <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>

    <!--AAD User read using Username-->

            
                <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Username">
                    <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
                    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonUsernameExchange</Item>
                        <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Username</Item>
                        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
    
                    </Metadata>
                    <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
                    <InputClaims>
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
                    </InputClaims>
                    <OutputClaims>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
                    </OutputClaims>
                    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
                    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
                </TechnicalProfile>
                
                
                <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingUserNameAndValidateStrongAuthenticationEmailAddress">
                    <DisplayName>Reset password using username</DisplayName>
                    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
                        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordchange1.1</Item>
                        <Item Key="AllowGenerationOfClaimsWithNullValues">true</Item>
                        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationStringsAreNotEqual">An account could not be found for the provided user ID.</Item>
                        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">Your account has been locked. Contact your support person to unlock it, then try again.</Item>
                        <Item Key="LocalAccountType">Username</Item>
                        <Item Key="LocalAccountProfile">true</Item>
                        <!-- Reduce the default self-asserted retry limit of 7 for the reset journey -->
                        <Item Key="setting.retryLimit">3</Item>
                    </Metadata>
                    <CryptographicKeys>
                        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
                    </CryptographicKeys>
                    <OutputClaims>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
                    <!--    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mail" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" /> -->
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emails" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sub" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" /> 
                    </OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromObjectID" />
                    </OutputClaimsTransformations>
                    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingUserNameAndValidateStrongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
                    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
                </TechnicalProfile>
                
                
                <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingUserNameAndValidateStrongAuthenticationEmailAddress">
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
                        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
                    </Metadata>
                    <InputClaims>
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.userName" Required="true" />
                    </InputClaims>
                    <OutputClaims>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountEnabled" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" /> <!--displayName added to Claims-->
                    </OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertEmailAndstrongAuthenticationEmailAddressAreEqual" />
                        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertAccountEnabledIsTrue" />
                        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromObjectID" />
                    </OutputClaimsTransformations>
                    <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-ReadCommon" />
                </TechnicalProfile>
                
                
                <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-ReadCommon">
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
                        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
                    </Metadata>
                    <OutputClaims>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
                    </OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateEmailsFromOtherMailsAndSignInNamesInfo" />
                        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AddStrongAuthenticationEmailToEmails" />
                    </OutputClaimsTransformations>
                    <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
                </TechnicalProfile>
                <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-Input">
                    <DisplayName>Self Asserted</DisplayName>
                    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
                        <Item Key="AllowGenerationOfClaimsWithNullValues">true</Item>
                    </Metadata>
                    <CryptographicKeys>
                        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
                    </CryptographicKeys>
                    <OutputClaims>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
                        <!-- Note: Claims such as emails are not listed here because without a ValidationTechnicalProfile when SelfAsserted-Input is shown to the user,
                        the user will be prompted for such claims. As a result, that claim is kept in the technical profiles that have ValidationTechnicalProfile -->
                    </OutputClaims>
                    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
                </TechnicalProfile>
            </TechnicalProfiles>
        </ClaimsProvider>

            

            <!-- tech profile for MFA related work Start-->
            



                <ClaimsProvider>
                        <DisplayName>Self Asserted</DisplayName>
                        <TechnicalProfiles>
                            <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-Select-MFA-Method">
                            <DisplayName>Allow user to choose their MFA Method</DisplayName>
                            <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                            <Metadata>
                                <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
                            </Metadata>
                            <OutputClaims>
                                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail" Required="true"/>
                            </OutputClaims>
                            </TechnicalProfile>

                            <TechnicalProfile Id="EmailVerifyOnSignIn">
                            <DisplayName>EmailVerifyOnSignIn</DisplayName>
                            <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                            <Metadata>
                                <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
                            </Metadata>
                            <InputClaims>
                                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" />
                            </InputClaims>
                            <OutputClaims>
                                <!-- Required claims -->
                                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isActiveMFASession" DefaultValue="true"/>
                                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email"/>
                            </OutputClaims>
                            <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                                <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteMFAMethod">
                                </ValidationTechnicalProfile>
                            </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                            <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-MFA" />
                            </TechnicalProfile>       
                        </TechnicalProfiles>
                        </ClaimsProvider>

                         <ClaimsProvider>
                                    <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
                                    <TechnicalProfiles>

                                        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteMFAMethod">
                                        <Metadata>
                                            <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
                                            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">false</Item>

                                        </Metadata>
                                        <InputClaims>
                                            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
                                        </InputClaims>
                                        <PersistedClaims>
                                            <!-- Required claims -->
                                            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
                                            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
                                            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail" />
                                            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
                                        </PersistedClaims>
                                        <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
                                        <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
                                        </TechnicalProfile>
      
                                    </TechnicalProfiles>
                              </ClaimsProvider>


    </ClaimsProviders>



        <!--MFA user Journey started-->
    
    
        <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignInMFAOption">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
      
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>

            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninUsernameExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninUsernameExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Username" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
 
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonUsernameExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonName" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        
        <!--Sample: If uses is enrolled for MFA, ask the user to select the preferred method-->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Select-MFA-Method" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Select-MFA-Method" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>


        <!--Sample: MFA with email-->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false" > 
               <Value>extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail</Value>
              <Value>email</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="Email-Verify" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="EmailVerifyOnSignIn" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer"/>

      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb"/>
    </UserJourney>

        <!-- MFA user Journey ended-->
```

Comment: Other than the domain etc. did you change anything else?

Comment: Yes I did.   In the claims transformation, the reference that I used is strongAuthenticationEmailAddress whereas the policy in the github showed "signinName".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" is null then.

The copy is done in "SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" in step 1.

"strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" is only available after the read in step 3.